# Can I somehow convert attachments I get from Outlook Add In to pdf?

Tags: c#, .net, outlook, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I am currently making an Outlook Add In and I successfully got the attachments from an email.
Here is the attachment:
[image]

And here is the method:

```
public static List<AttachmentResponse> GetAttachments(
        AttachmentSampleServiceRequest request)
    {
        // Create an ExchangeService object, set the credentials and the EWS URL.
        var service = new ExchangeService
        {
            Credentials = new OAuthCredentials(request.AttachmentToken),
            Url = new Uri(request.EwsUrl)
        };
        var result = new List<AttachmentResponse>();

            var getAttachmentsResponse =
                service.GetAttachments(request.Attachments.Select(attachment => attachment.id).ToArray(),
                    null,
                    new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.FirstClassProperties,
                        ItemSchema.MimeContent));
            var getAttachmentResponsesFiltered = getAttachmentsResponse.Where(file =>
                file.Result == ServiceResult.Success && file.Attachment.ContentType == "application/pdf");

            {
                result.AddRange(from attachmentResponse in getAttachmentResponsesFiltered
                    let fileAttachment = attachmentResponse.Attachment as FileAttachment
                    let base64String =
                        Convert.ToBase64String(fileAttachment?.Content, 0, (int) fileAttachment?.Content.Length)
                    select new AttachmentResponse
                    {
                        Id = attachmentResponse.Attachment.Id, Name = attachmentResponse.Attachment.Name,
                        Type = attachmentResponse.Attachment.ContentType, FileBase64 = base64String
                    });
            }
            return result;
    }
```

Comment: @KJ, Yes, the type is pdf on this file, but on others isn't. Lets say there are .xlsx and .docx files which i would like to convert to .pdf. Do you think that is possible?

Comment: Is that a VSTO addin? Why are you using EWS then?

Comment: Have you tried using the Outlook object model for extracting pdf attachments from Outlook directly instead of contacting the server-side for that?

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev what does your comment mean? I tried googling what you said but nothing makes sense

Comment: @MatejDodevski is there any reason why you chose to use EWS over OOM in the add-in?

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev no, not in particular, would you suggest anything different?

Comment: The standard and trivial way is to deal with a local data already received from the server if you deal with a cached Exchange mode in Outlook. So, using the `Attachments` property form the OOM is the right choice.

Answer (score 0):

The Open XML SDK which you could use on the server-side doesn't provide anything for generating PDF files. You may try to use something like [iText](http://itextpdf.com/) or [iTextSharp](https://github.com/itext/itextsharp) or any other third-party components designed for the server-side execution.

In case of COM add-ins there is no need to use EWS at all. Use the `Attachments` property of Outlook items to deal with attached files and items. The [MailItem.Attachments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.attachments) property returns an `Attachments` object that represents all the attachments for the specified item. You can access attachments in the collection by using the either the index number of the object, or a value used to match the default property of an object in the collection. For example, here is a sample VBA code which illustrates how you could use the Outlook object model from your add-in:

```
Sub SaveAttachment() 
 Dim myInspector As Outlook.Inspector 
 Dim myItem As Outlook.MailItem 
 Dim myAttachments As Outlook.Attachments
 
 Set myInspector = Application.ActiveInspector 
 If Not TypeName(myInspector) = "Nothing" Then 
   If TypeName(myInspector.CurrentItem) = "MailItem" Then 
     Set myItem = myInspector.CurrentItem 
     Set myAttachments = myItem.Attachments 
     'Prompt the user for confirmation 
     Dim strPrompt As String 
     strPrompt = "Are you sure you want to save the first attachment in the current item to the Documents folder? If a file with the same name already exists in the destination folder, it will be overwritten with this copy of the file." 
 
     If MsgBox(strPrompt, vbYesNo + vbQuestion) = vbYes Then 
       myAttachments.Item(1).SaveAsFile Environ("HOMEPATH") & "\My Documents\" & myAttachments.Item(1).DisplayName 
     End If 
   Else 
     MsgBox "The item is of the wrong type." 
   End If 
 End If 
End Sub
```

Comment: But I'm not developing a Visual studio add in, my app is a ReactJs app making calls to a .Net Api I'm guessing this is limited to a visual studio add in ?

Comment: Ohhh... I see now. I was confused by the C# language which is used for developing COM add-ins. Anyway, I've updated the post with a valid information for your needs.